# Debian: nginx using an extreme amount of disk I/O

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, hard-drive, io

We're currently haveing an issue with one of our nginx servers. It's using an extreme amount of disk I/O.

It's the / (root - cciss/c0d0) partition that's being abused.

See picture of iotop here:
http://imgdrp.com/MziB

iostat:
[ehttp://imgdrp.com/vpzw](http://imgdrp.com/vpzw)

nginx is installed in /usr/local/nginx

Logging has been disabled (as far as i can see (cant find any logs being written to and i believe that all has been disabled in the conf files))

The files nginx servs (php files) is located on another harddrives/partition.

What is it that are creating this I/O? How can i find out which files / commands that are creating the I/O

Looking forward to hearing from you.

/Rasmus

Answer (score 2):

Are you using nginx as a reverse proxy in front of an app server?  If so, the disk IO is likely due to a lack of allocated upstream buffers in nginx (proxy, FastCGI, etc.).

Grep your nginx logs for "an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file" to be sure.

If reverse proxying:  http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule

If using FastCGI: http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,217034